# How to find Missing Indexes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql

5 and i want to identify missing indexes in it. Can somebody please help me to identify ? This will help us to increase the performance of query that leads to application.

Comment: You mean that you want to find the tables which do not have indexes?

Comment: nope not like that, if i am executing particular query and if it is missing some column in indexes which can leads to faster execution of query after adding/including that column in index or the query executing without indexes.

Comment: In SQL Server in execution plan query optimizer suggest the missing index and its percent of increase in executing the query kind of looking in MySQL.

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40407/mysql-logging-queries-which-would-execute-without-using-indexes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best what I can think of is to use the **[EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)** to check the execution plan of your query with index and without index and then see the difference in query performance.

You can also refer:

- [Does MySQL exectution plan depend on available indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95854/does-mysql-exectution-plan-depend-on-available-indexes)
- [Using EXPLAIN to Write Better MySQL Queries](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)
- [How to find un-indexed queries in MySQL, without using the log](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/08/18/how-to-find-un-indexed-queries-in-mysql-without-using-the-log/)

Comment: Note: Workbench has Visual Explain built-in, so also consider checking that.